# Add file to jenkins workspace with docker

Tags: jenkins, docker

In Docker i have installed Jenkins successfully. When i create a new job and i would like to execute a sh file from my workspace, what is the best way to add a file to my workspace with Docker? I started my container with this: `docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home jenkins`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy a file from your file system to the container with a simple command from your terminal.

> docker cp [OPTIONS] LOCALPATH|- CONTAINER:PATH

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

example:

```
docker cp /yourpaht/yourfile <containerId>:/var/jenkins_home
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on how the planned lifecycle of your Jenkins container is. If it is just used temporarily and does no harm if the data is gone, `docker cp` as NickGnd suggested will do the trick.

But since the working data of Jenkins like jobconfigs, system configs and workspaces will only live inside the container, all of it will be gone once the container is removed, so if you plan to have a longer running Jenkins environment, you might want to persist the data outside of the container so it will survive recreating the container, launching new container versions and so on. This can be done with the option `--volume /path/on/host:/path/in/container` or its short form `-v` on `docker run`.

There is also the option of `--volumes-from` which you can use to mount to keep the data in one "data container" and mount it into your Jenkins container.

For further information on this, please have a look at [The docker volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/)